# Problemas con modificar lineas en TXT

Tags: python, regex

estoy teniendo problemas en "evolucionar" un script para limpiar lineas de un TXT, adjunto ejemplo de TXT:

```
Fri Oct 14 22:27:49.100 EDT

Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lo0                up          up          Loopback0 interface configured by Netmiko
Lo55               up          up          
Lo100              up          up          ***MERGE LOOPBACK 100****
Lo111              up          up          Configured by NETCONF
Nu0                up          up          
Mg0/RP0/CPU0/0     up          up          DO NOT TOUCH THIS !
Gi0/0/0/0          admin-down  admin-down  ANSIBLE NXOS TEST
Gi0/0/0/1          admin-down  admin-down  test
Gi0/0/0/1.100      admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/2          admin-down  admin-down  Link to P2 configured by Netmiko
Gi0/0/0/3          up          up          Configured by Ansible !!!!!!!!
Gi0/0/0/4          up          up          Updated by Ansible using Jinja Template
Gi0/0/0/5          up          up          Configured by Ansible !!!!!!
Gi0/0/0/6          admin-down  admin-down  Updated by Ansible using Jinja Template
Gi0/0/0/6.11       admin-down  admin-down
Lo20               admin-down  admin-down  
Lo22               up          up          Loopback para pruebas
[K --More--           [KLo69               admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/3/3/4          up          up          A SDH TMU(C3387H62 18/1)ID_1690882-1690884
Gi0/3/3/4.852      up          up          TMU a Red BIT
[K --More--           [KGi0/3/3/4.853      up          up          Configured by Ansible !!!!!!
Gi0/3/4/2.256      up          up          Frontera Cliente A
Gi0/3/4/2.257      up          up          Frontera Cliente B
[K --More--           [KGi0/3/4/2.261      up          up          Frontera Cliente C
Te0/7/0/3          admin-down  admin-down  
Mg0/RP0/CPU0/0     down        down        
Mg0/RP1/CPU0/0     admin-down  admin-down  
[KRP/0/RP0/CPU0:ROUTER1#
```

y el script es el siguiente:

```
list_txt = [ruta/"prueba.txt"]

for txt in list_txt:

  with open(txt, "r") as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

  with open(txt, "w") as fw:
    for line in lines:

      if not re.match("-{5}|\s+|([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)", line):
        fw.write(line)
```

Con este script logro borrar las lineas de la fecha de arriba de todo, las lineas en blanco y las lineas donde son puros guiones medios el problema es q estoy intentando agregar 2 cosas:

1- Agregar al regex que si contiene la palabra "CPU" por lo que se borrarian las lineas:

```
Mg0/RP0/CPU0/0     down        down        
Mg0/RP1/CPU0/0     admin-down  admin-down  
[KRP/0/RP0/CPU0:ROUTER1#
```

2 - Por otra parte necesito borrar ese agregado raro que se agrega en algunas lineas como por ejemplo:

```
[K --More--           [KLo69               admin-down  admin-down
```

y que quede limpio de esta manera:

```
Lo69               admin-down  admin-down
```

Este ultimo intento hacerlo mediante txt.lstrip("[K") pero no surgio efecto, lo estoy haciendo alguna forma incorrecta y no funciona y el Regex no estoy dando con la tecla tampoco y no puedo agregar la palabra CPU, no tengo tan claro como generar los Regex claramente.

Idealmente me gustaria podes agregar todo al script existente para no acomplejizar tanto, podrian darme una mano por favor?

Comment: Solo puedes utilizar regex o es valido emplear el operado `in`?

Comment: Como estas GmrYael? perdon, capas el titulo confunda y deba modificarlo, dije Regex ya que el mayor filtro esta basado en Expresiones Regulares y no, no es necesario solo usar regex, lo q yo intente fue primero q nada agregar la palabra "CPU" al `re.match` pero claramente lo hice mal porque no surgio efecto, en cuanto al `lstrip` intente justamente hacer un `in` pero tampoco logre hacerlo de forma efectiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay veces que hacer un regex que cumpla multiples condiciones es más complicado que hacerlo de forma tradicional:

```py
for txt in list_txt:
    with open(txt, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    
    with open(txt, "w") as fw:
        for line in lines:
            line = line.replace('[K', '')
            line = line.replace('--More--', '')
            line = line.strip() # Limpia espacios sobrantes y el salto '\n'
            if not line: # Si es una linea en blanco
                pass
            elif re.match('[\w]{3}\s[\w]{3}\s[0-9]', line): # Si es fecha
                pass
            elif line.startswith('Interface'):
                pass
            elif line.startswith('---'):
                pass
            elif 'CPU' in line:
                pass
            else:
                fw.write(line + '\n')
```

`[*]` Posiblemente haya un mejor regex para detectar la fecha, pero no soy muy experto en la materia.

Comment: Como estas aeportugal? bueno, estaba muuuuuy cerca de poder solucionarlo pero estaba teniendo un problema en el orden o la forma de como estaba iterando los datos y lei tu solucion y me terminaste de iluminar!!! mil gracias!!! adjunto mi solucion final al post porque no me da el limite de caracteres, abrazo!

Answer (score 0):

Añado la solucion final que he podido darle de la forma mas reducida posible:

```
for txt in list_txt:

  with open(txt, "r") as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

  with open(txt, "w") as fw:
    for line in lines:

      if re.match("-{5}|\s+|([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)", line) or re.search("CPU", line):
        pass
      elif "[K" in line:
        line2 = line.rindex("[K")
        line3 = line[line2+2:]
        fw.write(line3)
      else:
        fw.write(line)
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).